# transactions traffic jam possible?

Tags: transactions, weaknesses

or there is security from that?

Comment: I don't understand any of the questions you're asking. 1) What empty space? 2) 'bloody hell reachmen'? 3) You're talking about Sidechain Elements, right?

Comment: 1) each block got empty space. I mean block close every something like 10mins as for now it's about 60% of 1MB so the 40% is still empty space that could also contain transactions? 2) let's say that men that always try to centralize system for control it. 3) yes.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: later. no time for that right now. thanks for mensioning.

Comment: As @NateEldredge already mentioned, each question post should only ask about one topic. I will put your question on hold and suggest that you edit this post to reduce it to one topic, then post the other questions as separate posts. When this question has been improved, please flag it for reopening.

Comment: people afraid to answer now :-D or nobody know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprise surprise!

Smart people has done it already and made an interesting stress-test that You, my dear friend, can read about right [here](https://tradeblock.com/blog/bitcoin-network-capacity-analysis-part-5-stress-test-analysis) - this is **Part 5** that have links to other parts as well. Probably you want to start from the beginning then have a good read!

Answer (score 0):

This site is intended to be one question per post and your questions don't really make sense. But maybe if I answer your first question you can use that knowledge to improve your further questions and ask those separately.

Blocks do NOT have empty space. 60% full means the size is 60% of the limit, but of course only that 60% is sent over the network and stored.

If the limit gets raised to 20MB it does NOT mean all blocks will be 20MB. The size will still be exactly the same as before until demand starts growing and there are actually more transactions to be put into those blocks.

Comment: that morning I tried to concentrate what I don't understand all in one. it seems not make sense for others but me. guess I was too busy to turn my head on :p